# Open an Access file without the security warning message

Tags: security, ms-access, vbscript

I am creating a script to print a report using a macro from an Access database and I am trying to make it automatic for every Monday. However when my script is opening the file, there is the security warning and I need to click open to continue.

> This file may not be safe if it contains code that was intended to harm your computer. Do you want to open this file or cancel the operation?

Is there a way to bypass this security message when opening the database or to change the security options just for the script?

Here is the code:

```
Dim accessApp
Set accessApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accessApp.Visible = False
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase "C:\db1.mdb"

accessApp.Run "MyMacro"
accessApp.Quit

Set accessApp = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: That's the whole point of security, you can't bypass it without the users consent, in this case the way to get around it is run the database from a "Trusted Location" which the user can define inside the Access options dialog, they will also have to modify their macro security settings.

Comment: What exactly is "the security message"?

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks for you answer, it seems that we can also configure the reg key, but not in Windows Server, I have putted it on a trusted location, it is now working.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers "Opening "C:\db1.mdb" The file may not be safe if it contains code that was intended to harm your computer. Do you want to open this file or cancel the operation" with 3 buttons (open, cancel, help)